# Hangfire: How to run job every x minutes, where x is more 60

Tags: c#, cron, scheduling, hangfire

I have to create job that does some stuff. The job's repeat interval is configurable. The problem is that the interval can set up from `15` up to `120` minutes with a step of `15`. We use Hangfire on our site and it is already running a bunch of other jobs. Hangfire uses CRON expressions, which can't take more than `59` minutes as far as I know. How can make Hangfire execute a job every `75`, `90` etc. minutes?

Comment: Cron doesn't allow to use more than 59 minutes. Hangfire throws an exception

Comment: found any solution for this?

Answer (score -1):

You can use: "0 */2 * * *" to run the job every second hour

See: https://crontab.guru/#0_*/2_*_*_* and try different settings